# Best practice to show one input field value has been modified automatically in a web form

Tags: jquery, forms, web

I am working on a web order confirmation form that has a few fields including a desired ship date. The ship date default value can be modified by a function based on the other fields value.  I refresh the default date when the user changes these other fields.

What is the best way to visually let the user know the default date has been modified ?

FYI, I am using jQuery but a non technical answer would work.

Comment: There is no "best" way. It's a visual design decision and there are numerous ways to do this.

Comment: I guess what I am looking for are examples of what some websites do so I can try them and decide what is the best option for me in this particular case.

Comment: this is accualy a good question that requires some (css + js events) tricks to flash the input on automatic updates but not on manual. I suggest you create some logic to know if the `onchange` event was fired without `oninput` after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done by implementing a change event handler.  I usually just change the color to red when the change event is received.

```
$("input").change(function() { 
                      this.css("color", "red"); 
                  });
```

Of course, you can change any visual aspect of the field or its surrounding elements to indicate that the value has been changed.

Something somewhat more sophisticated might compare the post-change value to the field's original value so that only truly-changed values would reflect their having been changed.